# Getting source code from url after loading JS

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2

Currently i am facing an issue.

consider the URL http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/, here if you look at the source code from view-source in browser it is different from the inspect-element version

Now here is the issue the inspect element version contains HTML source which is fully loaded(via JS, ajax etc) and that is what i required

```
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page_content = page.read()
```

above does not give fully loaded version, also using selenium will not be possible since the webdriver will be used and in my system it may or may not be present.

So currently i am looking for a workaround, other library maybe.

Comment: You know you can get the information loaded by an ajax call? And information loaded by JS has to be generated by local data, wich you'll already have.

Comment: Yeah but this all could be complicated procedure depending on the number of calls, i am looking for a simple solution.

Comment: That totally depends on what you want to scrape. I heard Scrapy and some kind of plug in could parse and use javascript. But I'm not sure about it. Why do you want to scrape js btw?